# Fading header and footer without jquerymobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Is there a way to achieve JQueryMobile's fading [header or footer effect](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/toolbars/footer-persist-a.html) without utilizing the entire mobile version of jQuery?

I don't want to load the mobile library if I don't need it. I am using regular jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you probably just need to bind your fade effects to the `scroll()` method.

Maybe something like:

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
      $(".header, .footer").fadeOut("slow").fadeIn("slow"); 
    });
```

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

**UPDATE**

Here is a simple example, but you would need to fix the multiple calls to the fadein/fadeout methods, possibly with an animation and a variable to test if its being animated already.

http://jsfiddle.net/VdxHe/

Comment: I think I can use timeouts to address that issue, but this relies on `position:fixed` which is a known issue for mobile devices

Comment: Ok, does my solution answer your question?

Comment: It doesn't. I cannot use `position:fixed` and that is a critical portion of the effect.